# Airtrack-DP-1 barcode printer - needs to "install" with a different default name

Tags: printing, printer

We have AirtrackDP-1 label printers we use to print barcodes for inventory tracking.

Some of my users seem to have an predilection for unplugging them.

The problem here is each station has 2 printers: one for "large" labels, and one for "small" labels.
So in the VB in Excel that has been written (which is not the problem here) the printers it points at were given different names.  (AirTrack-DP-Small, or Large).

- Can I write a small start-up script for the printers, on an SD Card, so when they power up they name themselves appropriately?
- Like install with a default name we give them, rather then the standard?

I remember reading at one point they can understand a specific programming language, but for the life of me I can't find that page again.

Basically we need the printers to name themselves what we want them to, so every time somebody unplugs or powers them off in some other way,  I don't need to go rename the damn thing.

Windows 10 OS.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: affiliation is an attachment to an organisation. I think the word you're looking for is propensity, predilection, or maybe penchant. (Your friendly local saurus. Not just any old saurus, the saurus ;))

Comment: You are correct. I knew as I was typing it, that was not the word I was looking for.  But it's early where I am. :)